# How does Apple iCloud / CloudKit prevent users from abusing the public database?

Tags: ios, security, cloudkit

Is it possible for users to take my developer key on an iOS device and use that to upload data (outside of my app's programming) into the Public database in CloudKit?

Comment: Not just any old user, but yes.

Comment: @Wain do you have anything I can do to google for more info?